# Table permission problems when attempting to drop a table

Tags: sql, informix

Informix-SQL(SE) 4.10.DD6 (MS-DOS 6.22):

I have a table created as: "pcuser".tablename. I attempted to drop this table with:

```
DROP TABLE tablename;
```

and received the following error message:

```
545: No write permission for table pcuser.tablename.
```

Since my app is single-user and I'm not concerned with restricting privileges for any table, I installed ISQL 4.10 without password protection (i.e. no user name or password is required to startup the SE engine). So the default and only user name/table owner is always "pcuser". With ISQL 2.10, I didn't have to specify "table-owner".tablename when dropping, creating, reading or writing to a table. However I did grant all on tablename to public and grant dba to public. I also executed the same grant statements in 4.10.

Do I have to specify the table owner when dropping a table like:

```
DROP TABLE "pcuser".tablename;
```

Sorry, I don't have the documentation for ISQL 4.10.

The following are perform.out screen outputs of SYSTABAUTH and SYSTABLES row for tablename:

```
SYSTABAUTH:

grantor            [pcuser  ]
grantee            [public  ]
tabid              [102        ]
tabauth            [su-idxa]


SYSTABLES:

tabname            [tablename           ]
owner              [pcuser  ]
dirpath            [C:\DBFILES.DBS\TABLENAME        ]
                   [                                ]
tabid              [102        ]
rowsize            [256   ]
ncols              [48   ]
nindexes           [5     ]
nrows              [1082594    ]
created            [07-13-2010]
version            [9          ]
tabtype            [T]
audpath            [                                ]
                   [                                ]
```

Below are two sql procs in my app. The first one properly execs, but the second one fails with the err 545 on the drop table statement:

```
{CREATEDB.SQL - First SQL Proc}

DROP DATABASE dbfiles;

CREATE DATABASE dbfiles;

CREATE TABLE tablename
    (
     col1 char(18),
     col2 char(60),
     [...]
    ) in "C:\DBFILES.DBS\TABLENAME";

LOAD FROM "tablename.unl" INSERT INTO tablename;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tablename_idx1 ON tablename (col1);

GRANT ALL ON tablename TO PUBLIC;

GRANT DBA TO PUBLIC;

UPDATE STATISTICS;

---

{DROPTAB.SQL - Second SQL Proc}

DROP TABLE tablename;
           ^
           ERROR 545: No Write Permission....
```

Comment: You don't normally need to locate the files specifically - so what happens if you drop the IN clause in the create step?  Does the DROP step work?  What about if you keep the TABLENAME component in DOS 8.3 format (so you specify `IN "C:\DBFILES.DBS\TBLNAME"`)?

Comment: @Jonathan: The "CREATE TABLE...IN..." works fine! The reason I use it is to avoid SE from appending its journaling numbers to first five letters of SE filenames like for example SYSME101.DAT.. Do you think that could be the cause of write perm errors in sql scripts?.. I do use 8 chars max for table names in ISQL, I just used "TABLENAME" to describe examples. In ISQL 4.10 (DOS), as well as 2.10, if you use more than 8 chars for table names, DOS truncates anything over 8, thus enforcing 8.3.. I just added SYSTABAUTH row values to question. This problem didnt happen with 2.10!

Comment: @Jonathan: When I installed ISQL 2.10 (DOS), I chose username/password option so that no one could fire-up SE engine unless they supplied the right user-id and password. This also allowed me to login as user informix so I could manipulate all SYS* tables in .DBS directory (mainly to alter SYSTABLES cuz SE's .DAT and .IDX default naming method introduces problems when altering tables, reason for me later using CREATE TABLE ... IN "C:\DBFILES.DBS\TABLENAM";

Comment: I don't know enough about the DOS version of ISQL to be able to comment on user names and passwords.  If you're sticking with 8.3 names, that isn't the trouble.  I don't recommending changing the values for the system catalog files themselves, but futzing with user-defined table names and paths normally works OK.  (Also, my question wasn't whether the CREATE with IN worked; my question was whether the DROP worked without the IN.)  I simply have no idea what the perm errors are caused by - I don't know how the permissions system worked in the original, or how it is being faked now.

Comment: @Jonathan: OK, I re-created all tables without the IN option and now, drop tables and the rest of the scripts work!.. However, now unload statements dont unload any rows, when in fact there's 1M+ rows in the table, when the SQL script containing the unload stmt is part of a script menu item in SYSMENUITEMS.. THIS THING, i.e. ISQL 2.10/4.10, IS WEIRD!.. some things sporadically fail. I can't understand why when I override SE datafile name journaling, write perms become inhibited, and now seems db connection gets severed when nesting sql scripts in menu..guess later versions fixed the problems.

Comment: @Jonathan: In iiug.org's classics board, Lori Helton told me I could find 4.10 mans at: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ifxhelp/v0/topic/com.ibm.tools.doc/sql.html.. however when I visited this link, the oldest version available were 7.2.. Are there any other links for locating older versions of ifx mans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running '`finderr -545`', I get the information:

> -545  No write permission for table table-name.
>
> Check the accompanying ISAM error code for more information. With this
> database server, a database is a directory with the name dbname.dbs,
> while tables and indexes are files within that directory. You need to
> have read and write access to all these files in order to exercise
> normal database functions.

You will need to look at the directory permissions on the database directory (dbname.dbs).  If you are logged in as 'pcuser', you need to own the directory and have permission to remove files from it (and create files, etc).

I'm not sure how ISQL and SE from DOS (where there really weren't users) adapt to modern versions of Windows (where there are users).

If you were running on any other platform, I'd be counselling you against 'GRANT DBA TO PUBLIC'; that is a recipe for disaster.  I'm still not convinced it is a good idea, but I don't have any specifics that I can point to that definitively argue against it - but it feels wrong; you should be caring who accesses the database and who has the ability to rebuild the database.

Answering the question about 'Do I have to specify the user name in the DROP TABLE statement?', the answer is 'No'.  The error message is from a stage after the query has been parsed and validated; it understands the table name.  It is just that the user running the query appears to have insufficient privilege to do the requested operation.

Comment: in this specific case, it's C:\DBFILES.DBS in DOS 6.22.. No attributes on the .DBS dir have been set to write-protect it, unlike, say chmod 500 in unix which only gives owner read and execute perms. You could say the .DBS has the equivalent of chmod 777. I even tested adding/updating/removing rows with perform and it all works fine, however when trying to exec an sql proc which drops,creates and loads a .unl into the table, the proc fails at the 'drop table tablename' with err 545. I need to provide the lone user (the pawnshop owner) with full dba access so he canrun the reorg proc

Comment: Please see edited question with SYSTABLES row for tablename and SQL script. I don't expect any support for this legacy version, but appreciate all your feedback!